# preg_match Part of a url

Tags: regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a link that looks like this `http://site.com/numbers_and_letters/This_is_what-I-need_to-retrieve.html`

I basically need to retrieve this part: `This_is_what-I-need_to-retrieve`
And also replace the the dashes and underscores with spaces so it would end up looking like this: `This is what I need to retrieve`

I'm new to regex so this is what i'm using:
(it works but has poor performance)

```
function clean($url)
{
    $cleaned = preg_replace("/http:\/\/site.com\/.+\//", '', $url);
    $cleaned = preg_replace("/[-_]/", ' ', $cleaned);
    //remove the html extension
    $cleaned = substr($cleaned, 0,-4);  
    return $cleaned;
}
```

Comment: can you explain poor performance on cutting a simple string like that ?! how can you tell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've got isn't that bad. But maybe you can try comparing its performance to this:

```
preg_match('[^/]+$', $url, $match);
$cleaned = preg_replace('[-_]', ' ', $match);
```

**EDIT:**

> If all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail.

How about avoiding regex altogether? (I presume each input is a valid URL.)

```
$cleaned = strtr(substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1, -5), '-_', '  ');
```

This even removes the `.html` extension! (I'm making all the same assumptions you already seem to be making, *i.e.* that all links end in `.html`.) A brief explanation:

- [`strtr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) *translates* a set of characters, *e.g.* `-_`, to respective characters in another set, *e.g.* spaces. (I imagine it'd be more efficient than invoking the entire regex engine.)
- [`substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), you must know, but note that if the last argument is negative, *e.g.* `-5`, it indicates the number of characters from the end to *ignore*. Handy for this case, and again, probably more efficient than regex.
- [`strrpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php), of course, finds the last position of a character in a string, *e.g.* `/`.

Comment: I agree with @Adidi, though. It's surprising you'd notice performance issues on such a simple operation.

Comment: I'll try it out right now :D thanks, also it's noticeable when you process ~1000 links lol

Comment: @user2263996 - I edited this answer so refresh the page to make sure you see the latest.

Comment: the non-regex code works really well, feels ALOT faster, the only problem is that the output is coming out with an extra '/' in the beginning, ex: /This is what I need to retrieve

Comment: @user2263996 - You should be able to figure that out yourself ;) but the solution's been edited. Needed to add one to the index.

Comment: lol i actually tried that a few seconds before you posted it and it works ahah its almost 4am, i should really get some sleep. And THANK YOU, it works great now!